# Complete Custom Style Part of Site

Tags: customization, css

I have a wordpress site, and I need to apply custom styles to one page, I see the custom styles option, and some of them work, but others get overwritten. Is there a way I can apply strictly my own styles to a portion of the page?

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: Your question is unclear - what is the 'custom styles' option? What theme/plugin are you using? Could this be more of a CSS question then a WordPress question?

Comment: @shea a lot of themes include a custom styles panel within the Appearance menu, it's a pretty common thing I've seen in WordPress.

Comment: @WillLanni It is, however, specific to the plugin or theme and the implementation will vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open your theme functions.php.

   1. FTP/Server access: Navigate to your WP install and look in /wp-content/themes/[your theme folder]
   2. Via the WP Dashboard: Appearance > Editor, then look for Theme Functions (functions.php) in the right column
2. Add the following to add a custom style sheet (replace "custom-style.css" with a better style sheet name, and replace 'your-page-slug' with the slug of the page you wish to add the custom style to):

   ```
   // script manager template for registering and enqueuing files
   function childtheme_script_manager() {
       // register custom style on your specific page
       if (is_page('your-page-slug')) {
           wp_register_style('custom-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom-style.css');
           wp_enqueue_style ('custom-css');
       }
   }
   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'childtheme_script_manager');
   ```
3. Create a style sheet in your theme folder called custom-style.css. Add your custom styles. Write the css to target whatever it is on your page that needs specific styling. Without anymore information or posting example code on that page, it's impossible to answer that.

Comment: Where is my theme folder, I have search endlessly for a "file upload" feature, but haven't found one. I'm a real CLI junky and I'm having a tough time with this bloated Graphical Interface.

Comment: Added the info into step one. :)

Comment: I see now I actually have to go in to my hosting client to modify the backend. That was very unclear.

Comment: Gotcha—my bad! Did the added info in step one clear that up?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your answer. I think I've got the general idea now. Thanks a ton!